# Hide System.out.println(three);

Tags: java

I want to prevent "System.out.println(three);" from printing anything.  Is there a way to hide this class? or can I structure my code differently to deliver the same results?

```
import java.util.*;
public class GreenCrud
{
  public static void main(String a[])
  {
    int initialWeight,numberOfDays;
    boolean check = true;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    {
      System.out.print("Enter the initial size of a green crud population (in pounds)"+"\n");
      initialWeight = sc.nextInt();
      System.out.print("Enter the number of days for which you want to compute the population"+"\n");
      numberOfDays = sc.nextInt();
      System.out.println("The size of the population of green crud after "+numberOfDays+" days is: "+calculateFinal(initialWeight,numberOfDays)+"\n");

    }
  }
  public static int calculateFinal(int initialWeight,int numberOfDays)
  {
    int fLength = numberOfDays/5;
    int one=1,two=1,three=0;
    for(int i=1;i<=fLength-1;i++)
    {
      three = one+two;
      one = two;
      two =three;
    }
    System.out.println(three);
    return initialWeight*three;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just remove that line? It doesn't do anything except printing.

Comment: Remove the line if you don't want it printed?

Comment: you can comment the line if you don't want it to work (//)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.out.println(three)` just prints the variable three. Delete the code or comment it out. You can comment code by adding two consecutive forward slashes.

Ex:

`//Hello World`

This WILL NOT print hello world :)

Answer (score 1):

The line: `System.out.println(three);` just prints the value of the variable `three`. If you remove the line it will no longer print the variable, but the manipulation of the variable will not change. If you want to keep the line while make the code inactive create a comment with two `//` characters in front of any given line.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to remove the line from the code and still do not want to print it.
You can use comment lines

```
//System.out.println(three);
```

this will make the line inactive while  executing